# Pass arguments of a Tagged Template Literals function to another one?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say there are two functions. The second use the first:

```js
func1 = function() {
    console.log(arguments)
}
func2 = function() {
    func1(arguments)
}

func1`foo`
func2`bar`
```

As we can see in the result, it's an argument of an argument. Bad.

I just would like to pass arguments of `func2` to `func1`.
In `func2` I tried calls below, but nothing work:

```
func1`arguments`
func1`${arguments}`
func1({...arguments})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as usual, if you don't want to pass the `arguments` object as a single value:

```
function func2() {
    func1(...arguments)
}
function func2() {
    func1.apply(this, arguments)
}
```